# wso2 How to unblock messageProcessor

Tags: wso2-esb

I have used a message Processor to call an end Point and make a guaranteed delivery. 
Sometimes it happens that a buggy message (incompatible data type with the end point WS) what causes  ERROR HTTP SC: 500
all the follow up messages (this time correct ones) are stuck due to the first blocking message.
How to unblock the message processor?
how to delete it from the queue? possibly is there a way how to correct it?

This is very dangerous if it happens in the production.

thank you!

message processor

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<messageProcessor
  class="org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ScheduledMessageForwardingProcessor"
  messageStore="SAPMoveMaterialOriginalMsgStore"
  name="SAPMoveMaterialMessageProcessor"
  targetEndpoint="SAPmaterialMoveProxyService" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <parameter name="client.retry.interval">900000</parameter>
  <parameter name="throttle">false</parameter>
  <parameter name="max.delivery.attempts">50</parameter>
  <parameter name="member.count">1</parameter>
  <parameter name="message.processor.reply.sequence">handleSAPResponse</parameter>
  <parameter name="message.processor.fault.sequence">fault</parameter>
  <parameter name="max.delivery.drop">Enabled</parameter>
  <parameter name="interval">1000</parameter>
  <parameter name="is.active">true</parameter>
</messageProcessor>
```

The end point

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint name="zsap_material_move" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <address trace="disable" uri="http://r3cr1.echternach.ieeintern:8020/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/zsap_material_move">
    <timeout>
      <duration>60000</duration>
    </timeout>
  </address>
</endpoint>
```

Comment: Can you show the log's from when the messages are stuck? It sounds like the endpoint gets disabled after receiving a 500 error. If so there is a solution for that.

Comment: ERROR - ForwardingService BlockingMessageSender of message processor [SAPMoveMaterialMessageProcessor received the ERROR HTTP SC: 500

Comment: I know that the first message is invalid (wrong input parameter type), but my problem is that this "invalid" message keeps blocking all good ones in the message store. I need to somehow remove or unblock the first blocking one. but how?

Comment: Can you add the code of your MessageProcessor?

Comment: the code has been added.

Answer (score 0):

Do not send the message directly to your endpoint, but to a proxy service where you define your own mediation and decide what kind of response to send back to the Message Processor

Comment: I tried to try it with a proxy service, however the Message Processor works only with End-points

Comment: I tried to put there a proxy service instead, but the engine ran into an error  **ERROR - ForwardingService BlockingMessageSender of message processor [SAPMoveMaterialMessageProcessor] failed to send message to the endpoint**

Comment: not sure to understand your problem : define your proxy and define an enpoint with the address of your proxy (something like http://localhost:8280/services/YourProxyService)

Comment: In your proxy, if you send back a response with http status code 200 or 500, the MessageProcessor's reply sequence will be executed. For all others http status code, the fault sequence will be executed

Answer (score 0):

In the Message Forwarding processor, It you do not want to retry any messages which returns HTTP 500 you can specify "Non retry http status codes" to avoid. Also if you set the "Maximum redelivery attempts" property and set "Drop message after maximum delivery attempts" to true it will drop the message without blocking the processor. Also in the Fault sequence you can decide on the mediation login you need to perform on the Faulty message. You can refer the following screen for this.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I tried it out with the "Non retry http status codes" but it does not work. First of all, it is not possible to add this property over eclipse (Exception) so I had to do it directly on the server. When I did it and ran my test case (the first message is corrupted and follow up messages are ok), the message processor has recognized that the first message raises HTTP 500, hence no more repeated - what is good, however the message (with HTTP 500) keeps blocked two correct follow up messages. Thus they will be never carried out.

Comment: from my point of view, the correct behavior of the message processor would be to move forward for other messages waiting in the queue and try to carry them out.

Comment: concerning the message processor FAULT, it does not fire for HTTP 500 error. It did fire when the service was not available